# fixed field in hibernate query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

hi i want to make a hibarnate query, but in one field i want it to be static or contant string.
here's a an sql query equivalent to the hibernate query that i want to make

```
select sum(amount),sum(sales),"info" from products
```

for hibernate i did this but it doesn't work that way,here's the query that i used:

```
session.createquery("select sum(amount),sum(sales),:info from Products")
.setParameter("info","information")
.list()
```

but it gives  me java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ParameterTranslationsImpl.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterTranslationsImpl.java:63)
can someone help me because all i need is just a constant column that doesn't exist in the mapping.

i just want a result with hibernate query like this for example:

```
==>12,145,information
==>123,345,information
==>5555,3456,information
==>9872,1023,information
```

Comment: Could you show your entity?

Comment: the information  field  doesn't exist in the entity products it's just constant that i want to diplay with fields amount and sales that exist in the entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the same thing as in SQL. But don't use a named parameter to pass the constant. Embed it in the query:

```
 session.createquery("select sum(amount), sum(sales), 'information' from Products").list()
```

I fail to see the point of selecting a constant value, though.

Comment: i just need it for the display because this request is just a dummy one for explanation but thanks